# Script for opening a website and accessing a particular field

Tags: browser

I want to write a script where in I can open a website (like www.google.com) and navigate my cursor to particular field (like IMAGES on www.google.com) and then insert a string in a IMAGES field (like "abcd" in IMAGE field) and display the output. I don't know where to start from.

update:

I think i figured it out. This is my code.

```
 curl -d "ip=something&submit=Trace IP With IP Tracker" "ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php"; >> a1.
```

But now I am getting some weird reply saying I don't have permission to access this website on this server. Do anyone here have idea about it. – Swatesh Pakhare 11 mins ago

Comment: A terminal script? Using a terminal browser like `w3m` or `lynx`?

Comment: @phk i want script. In terminal, I can navigate easily. But how to do that in a script?

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptish ?

Comment: may "imacro" can do the job?

Comment: It sounds like you want to submit a form request ? First you have to work out what the form request should look like and this depends on the form.

Comment: @XTian can you explain me with an example. This is the link http://www.ip-tracker.org/ i am working on. I want to insert the IP addresses in the request form.

Comment: I think i figured it out. This is my code.                                                        curl -d "ip=something&submit=Trace IP With IP Tracker" "http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php" >> a1. But now I am getting some weird reply  saying I don't have permission to access this website on this server. Do anyone here have idea about it.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I wanna see which ip belongs to which domain or organisation.Just like nslookup. Basically I am doing IP look up